# Basic explanation and examples on mute variables

Tags: logic, terminology, education

I would like to get from you some feedback regarding mute variables. Specifically, I would love to get an easy definition or description, one that I could convey to high school kids. I would also need some examples, accordingly, to illustrate.

One last thing, a little bit more technical. I would love to know in which way mute variables in mathematics relate to mute variables in lambda calculus, as I know it from Logic.

Bets regards and thanks in advance.

Comment: What do you mean by "mute variable" in mathematics?

Comment: @NoahSchweber Maybe dummy variables??

Comment: I mean variables which are local, so that they can be used several times for different goals without incurring in contradiction.

Comment: You may find "Structure and Interpretation of Classical Mechanics" interesting. In my experience, compared to programmers, mathematicians handle scoping poorly and mathematical notation is often extremely unclear about the scopes of things or even that some construct is a binding form at all. (Personally, I think this is a major factor in why so many find calculus difficult. It is one of the first subjects taught where scoping is used non-trivially, but it has some of the worst notation for it and educators don't seem inclined to dedicate the time to explicitly discussing scoping.)

Comment: This is a very relevant comment, I think. Thanks. I am trained as a linguist to pay a lot of attention to the scope of binding....So that is probably the rationale behind  my question...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may think that a formula has an author and users. A formula can contain variables, that is, symbols that can be assigned values, very useful to parametrize. Such variables can be categorized by who, between the author and a user, is allowed to assign values.
$$f(x)=\sum_{i=1}^{10}x^i$$
Here the author has conveniently made use of the parametrization feature of variables with the variable $i$. She bound $i$ iteratively to the integers in the range $1$ to $10$. So $i$ is a bound variable.
At the same time the author gave the users of her formula the possibility to use that formula parametrically. That is, a user is free to assign a value to $x$, it's a free variable, it is open bound. Then for the user, the bound variable $i$ is not usable. It's dummy, so to say, from the user perspective, or it does not claim to be assigned, it's thus mute.

Moreover, as you say in your comment you can reuse the name $i$ in the same formula to represent different dummy variables, with no name clashing.

**EDIT:**

Here the same name $n$ is used to name two different dummy variables:
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{2}a_0+\sum_{n=1}^\infty a_n \cos (nx)+\sum_{n=1}^\infty b_n \sin (nx)$$
where
\begin{align}
a_0 &=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)dx\\
a_n &=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\cos(nx)dx\\
b_n &=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^\pi f(x)\sin(nx)dx\\
\end{align}

Comment: could you provide an example in which a dummy variable appears several times in a formula, with different values each? Thanks

Comment: trivially $f(x)=\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}x^i\right)\left(\sum_{i=1}^{10}x^i\right)$

Comment: A better example just added to the answer.

Comment: so the proper name is dummy variable? I have read mute variable sometimes.....and also when dealing with Logic, Lamdba calculus, etc....If someone could clarify the relation of those dummy variables to lambda, I would be very grateful.

Comment: @JavierArias You should get out of the habit of thought that things have a single "proper" name. It simply doesn't reflect reality, especially when it comes to notation. I have also seen "mute variable" used, though my impression is "dummy variable" is more common. I dislike both and would prefer "bound variable", which is even more common, though it depends on the community.

Comment: @DerekElkins. Well, bound variables are different, as far as I understand it. I mean, dummy variables are not bounded, they are free, so they are the opposite to what we linguist call a bound variable.....Am Iwrong?

Comment: @JavierArias I'm not a linguist, so I can't comment on how they use the term "bound variable" (though, I don't think it is that different). However, $i$ is not a free variable in $\sum_{i=0}^{10}x^i$. It is a bound variable and it is bound by the $\Sigma$, i.e. $\Sigma$ is a binding form. Similarly, $x$ is not a free variable in $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}f(x)dx$, it is bound by the integral sign. That said, in calculus often variables are reused and thus appear both bound and free, e.g. $\frac{df(x)}{dx}$ is like $D(x\mapsto f(x))(x)$ where $x$ appears both free and bound, no doubt adding confusion.

Comment: I have just found this......Are free variables the same as dummy varuables then?  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_variables_and_bound_variables

Comment: I'm used to "dummy variables" referring to the case in which a free variable doesn't orthographically occur in the formula (a thing which is often done to make certain semantics smoother), and I've never heard "mute" at all. But "free" versus "bound" is pretty unambiguous in the literature. If a variable can occur twice in the same formula with different interpretations, this is usually an indication that you have a *bound*, not a free, variable.

Comment: By the way, is there a way to copy and paste the formulas written in Mathlab here in order to insert them in a word document? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would this also qualify as valid example?  (x+a)^n=∑_(k=0)^n▒〖(n¦k) x^k a^(n-k) 〗